# How to import excel file into mysql with rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model Item

```
id | category_id | name | description | price | wall_th | size |
```

Items.rb

```
has_many :item_gosts
has_many :gosts, through: :item_gosts
has_many :item_steel_marks
has_many :steel_marks, through: :item_steel_marks
```

2 join tables
item_gosts and item_steel_marks

and have xlsx file with this data

```
| name     | |size  | |Gosts    |  |steel marks | description | |price |
|steel tube| |45x4  | |8734;8732|  |3сп; 20; 10 | L = 5-10,5  | |257664|
```

How do I import this file into mysql with the join table, if in file Gosts param = item_gosts, and steel marks params(3сп; 20; 10) for item_steel_marks?

Comment: Why do you have so many associations? Why not just it all in one table and one model?

Comment: to use the filter by state Standards and steel grades

Comment: What did you do so far to open and parse the excel file?

Comment: i can parse exel file without join tables but i need to parse with join tables

Answer (score 0):

I would export it to csv and then write a rake task that creates all the models from the csv. Something along the lines of:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Load Items"
task :load => :environment do
  CSV.foreach(MY_CSV_FILENAME, headers: true) do |row|
    row = row.to_hash.symbolize_keys
    Item.create(row)
  end
end
```

Edit: For join tables, I'll assume that you can split your excel in 5 tables: Items, ItemGosts, Gosts, ItemSteelMarks, and SteelMarks. Then you make them all into separate csv files and do something roughly like this:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Load"
task :load => :environment do
  create_models(MY_ITEM_CSV, Item)
  create_models(MY_GOST_CSV, Gost)
  create_models(MY_STEEL_MARKS_CSV, Steel)
  create_joins(MY_ITEM_GOSTS_CSV, :gosts, Gost, :gost_id)
  create_joins(MY_ITEM_STEEL_MARKS_CSV, :steel_marks, SteelMarks, :steel_mark_id)
end

def create_models(filename, model)
  foreach_table_row(filename) { |row| model.create(row) }
end

def create_joins(filename, relation, model, model_id)
  foreach_table_row(filename) do |row|
    item = Item.find_by(id: row[:item_id])
    item.send(relation) <<  model.find_by(id: row[model_id])
    item.save
  end
end

def foreach_table_row(filename)
  CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
    yield row.to_hash.symbolize_keys
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, I'll extend the example.